# Getting extra form controlName when use FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript

I created FormArray in angular 8 in the following way:

```
 ngOnInit() {
  this.assessmentForm = this.fb.group({
  generalassessment: this.fb.group({
    confirm: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    score: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    description: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  }),

  productArray: this.fb.array([ this.createItem() ]),
  cooperatorArray: this.fb.array([ this.createItem() ]),
  vehicleArray: this.fb.array([ this.createItem() ]),
  bankAccountArray: this.fb.array([ this.createItem() ]),
});
}



createItem(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
  confirm: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  score: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  description: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
   });
}



addItem(typeForm:string): void { 

  if(typeForm=='productArray'){ 
    this.productArray = this.assessmentForm.get('productArray') as FormArray;
    this.productArray.push(this.createItem()); 
  }
  if(typeForm=='cooperatorArray'){
    this.cooperatorArray = this.assessmentForm.get('cooperatorArray') as FormArray;
    this.cooperatorArray.push(this.createItem());
  }
 if(typeForm=='vehicleArray'){
   this.vehicleArray = this.assessmentForm.get('vehicleArray') as FormArray;
   this.vehicleArray.push(this.createItem());
 }
if(typeForm=='bankAccountArray'){
   this.bankAccountArray = this.assessmentForm.get('bankAccountArray') as FormArray;
   this.bankAccountArray.push(this.createItem());
} 
}


addForm(indexForm,typeForm:string){
 this.addItem(typeForm);
}
```

I called `addForm()` Function in HTML ngFor loop until create new controler in formArray but created extra controler in FormArray
ngFor array size is example 3 but calling `addForm()` Function over 20 time

I think my calling method `addform()` is wrong.

```
<ng-container formArrayName="productArray">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let productList of productsUsersList;let j=index">        
       <ng-container [formGroupName]="j" >
           <ng-container *ngIf="addForm(j ,'productArray')"></ng-container>
```

Comment: *ngIf="addForm(j ,'productArray')" makes no sense

Comment: so how create new form controler in form array?

Comment: @Kamal, not try create a form in *ngIf (I supouse that you can it), but I think that "the natural way" is make it in the .ts. Why not a simple (in .ts) `productsUserList.forEach((x,index)=>this.addForm(index,x)` (or similar)?